# htaccess mobile redirectioon to subdomain not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I'm using following htaccess code to redirect mobile users

```
    # Mobile Redirection
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ http://m.mydomain.com [R,L]
```

Problem is it works only ehen user type http://mydomain.com/ 
If I type http://mydomain.com/anyurl   it will not redirect to subdomain. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

You are matching the root url with the regex `^$`.

Try `^.*$`, and if you want to redirect to the relevant mobile page, the line should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]` (`$1` is the matched pattern in brackets).

Comment: I have made that change But the redirection stops with a message " The page isn't redirecting properly"
See http://sreejesh.in

Comment: I am seeing a missing DNS listing for [m.sreejesh.in](http://m.sreejesh.in), which means you didn't configure the subdomain correctly. If you are using cPanel this is relatively easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Change your rewrite rule to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://m.mydomain.com [R,L]
```

Comment: I have made that change But the redirection stops with a message " The page isn't redirecting properly" -- See www.sreejesh.in

Comment: Is m.sreejesh.in on DNS and if so, does it have it's own Apache VirtualHost? It is generally better to use client side content adaption (CSS media queries etc.) for content negotation than using server side negotiation, especially in your case since the website looks like it would share a common information architecture across devices.